# Mocking functions at a very deeper level with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

my file structure looks like below. I needed to mock a function which is three level deeper and not exported. Can someone help me figure out how to achieve this task please. My goal is not to send data to database.

```
file name c.js

exports.c.function3 = {
dbCall.then((data)=>data);
}
```

```
file name b.js

require("./c");
exports.b.function2 = ()=>{
c.function3()
.then((data)=>data);
}
```

```
filename - a.js

require("./b");
exports.function1 = ()=>{
b.function2()
.then((data)=>data);
}
```

```
file name - a.test.js
require("./a");
describe("Test cases a",()=>{


test("function1 should return data from db",()=>{
const dbCall = jest.spyOn(a,'function2.function3.dbCall');
dbCall.mockImplementation(()=>[1,2,3]);
function1.then((data)=>{
expect(data.length).toBe(3);
});
}
})
```

I tried multiple ways to mock the function, but none worked. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Jest with CJS by using `jest.mock()`.

I do not understand your CJS imports and async flow 100%.
But this works, hope it helps:

```
c.js

const dbCall = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => resolve("Data from database"))
}

exports.function3 = () => {
    return dbCall().then((data) => data)
}
```

```
b.js

const c = require("./c");
exports.function2 = () => {
    return c.function3()
        .then((data) => data);
}
```

```
a.js

const b = require("./b");
exports.function1 = () => {
    return b.function2()
        .then((data) => data);
}
```

```
a.test.js

jest.mock('./c', () => {
    return {
        function3: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
            new Promise((resolve, _reject) => resolve("Mocked data"))
        )
    };
});

const a = require("./a")

test("function1 should return data from db", () => {
    a.function1().then((data) => {
        expect(data).toBe("Mocked data");
    });
})
```

If you need the rest of c module intact, do like this:

```
jest.mock('./c', () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('./c')
    return {
        ...originalModule,
        function3: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
            new Promise((resolve, _reject) => resolve("Mocked data"))
        )
    };
});
```

Result:

```
> 75891489@1.0.0 test
> jest

 PASS  ./a.test.js
  ✓ function1 should return data from db (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.265 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

node: v18.12.1
jest: 29.5.0

Comment: It didn't throw ay error, but didn't invoke the mock function for me. I used a.__set__(b,mockObect) to mock b and c. I guess we were supposed to test b and c separately, but it was needed in my case for a particular use case.

Comment: In my example I don't mock module b.
Do you need to mock module b as well?

Comment: I didn't need to. Since I couldn't mock only "c" , I had to mock from  "b" onwards. The way "c" was imported in b is a little complicated in my original project. There were multiple versions of c and all of them were imported through a class which imports all versions of "c". That might be the reason. Anyways I am happy that I could mock and complete the test. I did write a test case for "b"  too for completeness.

Comment: Ok. Did my response help you out? If you want to mock partials of c but still keep the rest intact (it's being used in b?) then you can do that. I've updated my answer above to reflect it.